quarkus web socket drops connection after 1 minute
we are using quarkus java app for serving web socket and it drops connection after one minute ... is there any built in mechanism to use to keep the websocket connection active or do have to implement some sort of heartbeat or ping/pong mechanism and the client must keep sending this message until wants the connection active. What is the best practice here?

Do you use quarkus-websockets or quarkus-websocketx-next? In quarkus-websocketx-next, there's the quarkus.websockets-next.server.auto-ping-interval config property that can be used to set the interval after which, the server sends a ping message to a connected client automatically. There's a similar property for the client too.

we are using quarkus-websockets ... is quarkus-websockets-next stable?

It's still in the experimental phase. In the sense that the API may change in the future. But I believe that it's quite stable at this point, esp. the server part.
